# Простой запрос на выборку select из таблиц SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Так выглядит диаграмма бд]Есть sql запрос

```
select
  TOV.NTOV,
  SUM(DMS.KOL) as SUMKOL,
  round(SUM(DMS.CENA), 2) as SUMA
from TOV, DMZ, DMS
where DMS.PR=2
  and DMZ.DDM = ('2014-03-01') 
  and TOV.KTOV = DMS.KTOV
  and DMZ.NDM = DMS.NDM
group by TOV.KTOV
having count(*) >= 1
order by SUMA desc;
```

где TOV - товар, DMS - документ товара1, DMZ -документ товара2,
поля KTOV, NTOV - код товара и наименование соответственно,
KOL -количество, CENA - цена, PR - приход или расход товара (1 - приход, 2 - расход) и DDM - дата.

Нужно сделать выборку по заданной дате и вывести наименование товара, количество (итого за день), сумма (итого за день), по одному товару должна быть одна итоговая строка.

В данном варианте получаю ошибку:

> Столбец "TOV.NTOV" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не
>   содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.

Выводить нужно именно поле с названием товара, НО обязательно сгруппировать по id(это в задании). Надеюсь на вашу помощь,уже много вариантов было перепробовано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая СУБД? В разных слегка отличаются правила агрегации.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Для MSSQL вам надо перечислить в группировке все поля, которые вы выбираете в селекте, но для которых не производится вызов функции агрегации. В ответе ниже это уже правильно заметили.

Comment: Но как тогда мне вывести именно наименование, сгруппировав по коду товара ? + должна быть одна итоговая строка на товар

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  TOV.NTOV,
  SUM(DMS.KOL) as SUMKOL,
  round(SUM(DMS.CENA), 2) as SUMA
from TOV, DMZ, DMS
where DMS.PR=2
  and DMZ.DDM = ('2014-03-01') 
  and TOV.KTOV = DMS.KTOV
  and DMZ.NDM = DMS.NDM
group by TOV.KTOV, TOV.NTOV
having count(*) >= 1
order by SUMA desc;
```

альтернатива - выбор TOV.NTOV подзапросом, что-то вроде

```
select
  (select top 1 tt.ntov from tov tt where tt.ktov = t.ktov) as ntov,
  SUM(DMS.KOL) as SUMKOL,
  round(SUM(DMS.CENA), 2) as SUMA
from TOV t, DMZ, DMS
where DMS.PR=2
  and DMZ.DDM = ('2014-03-01') 
  and T.KTOV = DMS.KTOV
  and DMZ.NDM = DMS.NDM
group by t.KTOV
having count(*) >= 1
order by SUMA desc;
```

Но смысла в таком решении нет, т.к. результат выдаст точно такой же.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59361/discussion-on-answer-by-pashapash-----select---sql).

Answer (score 2):

1. `having count(*) >= 1` делать бессмысленно, т.к. в группировке автоматически будут лишь те значения, у которых количество строк ненулевое.
2. Ошибка логична, потому что в `select` у вас TOV.**N**TOV, а в `group by` у вас TOV.**K**TOV

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59360/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-----select---sql).